# Where are Aurcade score rules located?

Tags: aurcade, splatterhouse

I'm interested in running a Splatterhouse world record attempt at an Aurcade-supported arcade. While I was searching around for strategies and previous attempts, I found the current world record holder's video at

What interests me is this piece of the description:

> **It's worth noting that this run follows the Twin Galaxies & Aurcade ruleset for score in this game, which bans the use of the double KO tactic on the final boss, which is otherwise the most lucrative option to cash out your extra lives.** If this were allowed, then you would have to set up guaranteed double KO's with the blue orb timer, which is something on the order of 14+ minutes per double KO. You could also die to rocks at the end, but if you're on a good pace, the guaranteed route is the best option for consistency. Without the restrictions in this category, scores in the 1.2 - 1.3 million point range are possible.

This is news to me. I found the [game on Aurcade](http://www.aurcade.com/games/format.aspx?id=288) and it only lists dip switch positions and difficulty, nothing about forbidden strategies.

In general, where are Aurcade performance restrictions located?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstood that statement. The description just says that the run follows **both** *Twin Galaxies* and *Aurcade* ruleset for score, only because that user probably submitted their speedrun on both platforms, so the rules explained are a mix of both sites.

Aurcade only lists what you've linked, and I couldn't find any other rule, nor on its forum.

*Twin Galaxies*, however, wants you to follow [these rules](https://www.twingalaxies.com/game/splatterhouse/arcade):

> Setup Screen Menu Options
> Sound = On
> Difficulty = Normal
> Extra Man = 30,000, 70,000, every 50,000 after

> Special Rules: Your Record attempt ends when your lives run out OR **you defeat the final boss for the first time as it's possible to die after delivering the final blow, allowing you to defeat him again and again**. This is due to the fact he's 100,000 points, which is worth multiple extra lives. Continues are NOT allowed!

*Aurcade* doesn't mention this, but I feel this is a common lineguide for Splatterhouse submissions, also because it's a blatant exploit.